# ¿Cómo restauro el menú de Telerik en Visual Studio 2017 v.15.6.2?

Tags: telerik

Actualicé Telerik 2017R3 a 2018.1 y VS 2017 v.15.5.7 a v.15.6.2 y ha desaparecido del menú la pestaña de Telerik.

Ya probé la opción de reinstalar, reparar Telerik sin éxito.
Buscando en foros habla de instalar en linea la opción Telerik ASP. NET for AJAX y tampoco funciona.

He desinstalado todas las versiones de Telerik y eliminado todos los registros, reinicié e instalé telerik sin éxito.

Alguien ha pasado por ésto y lo ha resuelto ? Agradezco de antemano su ayuda...

Answer (score 0):

Para comentar que ya encontré la solución, la clave está en no instalar o en su caso **desinstalar todos los complementos de Progress Telerik Reporting**, despúes de eso solo restauré el Progress Telerik for WinForms 2018.1 y listo...apareció el menú Telerik en VS 2017 v15.6.2.

Otra solución más complicada es **1)**Desinstalar todos los complementos de Telerik desde Panel de Control **2)**Limpiar el registro con una herramienta o directamente con regedit **3)**Reiniciar **4)**Restaurar VS 2017 a la última versión **5)**Instalar Telerik excepto los Reporting.